# UICollectionViewCell displaying blank cells when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

I cannot seem to figure out why extra cells are being created and displayed when scrolling or sometimes when I dismiss another view controller to view the cells.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSInteger tmpIndex = indexPath.row+1; //addd 1 because userDetail is first element

    if ([self.model.order[tmpIndex] isKindOfClass:[Products class]])
    {
        Products *products = [self.model.order objectAtIndex:tmpIndex];

        if ([[products display] isEqualToString:kACTIVITY_GRID_CELL_ID])
        {
            ActivityCollectionViewGridCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kACTIVITY_GRID_CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.data = products;
            cell.delegate = self;
            cell.tag = indexPath.row;
            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCollectionViewListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kACTIVITY_LIST_CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.data = products;
            cell.delegate = self;
            cell.tag = indexPath.row;

            return cell;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OrderHeaders *orderHeaderBaskets = [self.model.order objectAtIndex:tmpIndex];
        ActivityCollectionViewListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kACTIVITY_LIST_CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.data = orderHeaderBaskets;
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.tag = indexPath.row;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

To my understanding it only adds the extra empty cells for this part of the code:

```
    else
    {
        ActivityCollectionViewListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kACTIVITY_LIST_CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.data = products;
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.tag = indexPath.row;

        return cell;
    }
}
else
{
    OrderHeaders *orderHeaderBaskets = [self.model.order objectAtIndex:tmpIndex];

    ActivityCollectionViewListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kACTIVITY_LIST_CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.data = orderHeaderBaskets;
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

Could this be because I am using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` multiple times ? Or is something else causing this ?

Also is there a way to check and remove the extra cells?

Comment: This might be because of cell reusability.

Comment: @SurajSukale this only happens when scrolling downwards

Comment: Does your `ActivityCollectionViewListCell` know how to handle `Products` AND `OrderHeaders`? Are you sure you are not just seeing empty `ActivityCollectionViewListCell`s?

Comment: The first line of this method says, "lie about the indexPath we're on".  Bugs will follow.  Instead, create a distinct branch of  logic for each sort of the *current row*, only concern yourself with the *current row*.

Comment: Try providing an empty footer view for the table to remove extraneous cells.